# Safari 6 Extension Popover reload en navigate

Tags: javascript, safari, safari-extension, safari6

I have developed a Safari Extension with a Popover that worked fine in Safari 5. I used the following code in Javascript to reload the page:
`safari.extension.popovers[0].contentWindow.location.reload();`

And the following code for go to an other HTML file:
`safari.extension.popovers[0].contentWindow.location.replace("second.html");`

But in Safari 6, if I use one of these codes Safari doesn't open the link only in the popover but also in the main window.

How can I fix this?